# Where should shared interfaces in Prism be placed?

Tags: c#, prism

I understand this could be interpreted as an opinion question, but it is technical and a problem I am currently trying to solve.

In the Prism documentation, it is stated that modules should have loose coupling with no direct references, only going through shared interfaces. Like in the following picture:

[image: Module dependencies]

My issue is, if only a few modules required an `IOrdersRepository`, the infrastructure is the wrong place for it, as this contains shared code for all of the modules. If I placed the interface in another module, then both modules will need to directly reference that one, breaking the loose coupling.

Should I simply create a library which contains this interface and doesn't follow the module pattern?

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: so what's your plan? creating a seperate assembly every time an interface istn't shared by "all of the modules"? I'd put it in the infrastructure, as this is code that is _potentially_ shared by all of the modules

Comment: I was thinking of creating a separate assembly for each shared set of interfaces (e.g. all of the interfaces for dealing with Orders). But what you are saying makes sense, I'm just concerned the infrastructure project will be full of interfaces which most modules don't require.

Comment: After @chopikadze's answer, I'm wondering how this solution would work if I ever wanted to re-use some of the services in another application? The approach of a separate interface assembly and an implementation module would mean the services could be use on a website for example.

Comment: @Lukazoid: Sorry, but I actually don't understand your last question. what do you mean under "re-use some of the services in another application"?

Comment: @chopikadze If I had a service, `IPaymentService` with a method `void PaySuppliers()`. I might want to allow this service to be used in the WPF application, like here, but I may want this service to be used in a windows service which runs every night, or through a web interface. The service should perform the exact same routine in all three situations, however by placing the interface in `Infrastructure`, I tie the service into the WPF application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be definitely `Infrastructure` module. Markus' argument is absolutely right - you shouldn't create separate assembly for each shared set of interfaces. It's much more better to have `Infrastructure` module with a lot of interfaces istead of a lot of modules with some interfaces in each one. Imagine, that one time you will find, that 2 of yours "set of interfaces" should use some shared interface! What will you do? Add yet one assembly for that "super-shared" interfaces? Or combine those modules to one? It's wrong I think.

So - definitely `Infrastructure` module!

PS. Imagine, that .NET Framework has 1000s libraries - one for collections, anotherone for math functions etc....

**UPDATE:**

Actually, I use `Infrastructure` module mostly for interfaces and very basic DTOs. All *shared* code I move to another assembly (like `YourApplication.UIControls`, `YourApplication.DAL` etc.). I haven't enough reasons to do exactly this way, but this is my way to understand Prism's recomendations. Just IMHO.

**UPDATE 2:**

If you want to share your service so wide - I think it absolutely makes sence to have structure like:

- `YourApplication.Infrastructure` - "very-shared" interfaces (like `IPaymentService`)
- `YourApplication.Modules.PaymentModule` - "very-shared" implementation of your PaymentService
- `YourApplication.WPF.Infrastucture` - infrastructure of your WPF application (in addition to `YourApplication.Infrastructure`
- `YourApplication.WPF.Modules.PaymentUI` - some WPF specific UI for your `YourApplication.Modules.PaymentModule`
- `YourApplication.WebSite.Modules.PaymentUI` - UI for web-site

And so on.. So, your modules will have almost always references to `YourApplication.Infrastructure` and `YourApplication.TYPEOFAPP.Infrastructure`, where `TYPEOFAPP` can be WPF, WebSite, WinService etc.. Or you can name it like `YourApplication.Modules.PaymentUI.WPF`..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what you're saying about the masses of assemblies sounds right and it would grow unmanageable. My concern with placing the service interfaces in the `Infrastructure` project is that it would make the re-use of services in other projects a nightmare (e.g. a website), as all of the service implementations would reference back to `Infrastructure`. This is where my idea for having a shared assembly for the interfaces, and an assembly/module for the implementations came from.

Comment: Thanks for the second update, seems like exactly the kind of thing I need. Allows for service re-use while still providing the prism modular approach. Thanks :)